# on key long click and single click on dialog custom view

Tags: android, dialog, keylistener

i want to get volume key single and longclick events on dialog as googled i got to know is not possible on dialog, so i decided to create a view in dialog and implement volume long press on that view

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(dialoglayout);
    dialoglayout.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
            {
                Log.w("dialog", "click");
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

not working this and i want to get long click also to this view

Answer (score 0):

why are you not making a custom dialog and than using single and long click...

for custom dialog please visit http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

and than use long click at button...

Comment: mine also custom dialog. dialoglayout is my custom view and i am implementing keylistner to dialoglayout only